# 400+ms overhead anytime rails accesses current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

my apps views are taking anywhere from 800-2000ms to load according to the logs.

I noticed for a page w/o accessing current_user the time is under 10ms... Anytime current_user is accessed it takes 400ms just to get current_user.

Any ideas why it is taking so long to get the current_user? Any way to track down where the lag is in performance?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it could be a database-related issue, or possibly some kind of middleware that's misbehaving.

Comment: Look at the log file to see the SQL statement executed. You might have to add an index based on how the user object is queried while trying to construct the current user.

Comment: Any before_filters that could be timing out? This can be file system corruption as well.  Check your volume's file system.

Comment: You might also check `User.find(x)` to if the delay only comes from the `current_user` method.

Comment: Very strange but it turned out that we were on rails 3.0.5 and moving to rails 3.0.9 fixed this. It was also only the user table casuing the issue. not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs should show you the database times as well as the render times.  See if they track.  i.e. high render times always implies a high database time.

There are various ways to profile rails if it is not a database issue.

The [Railscasts #98 Request Profiling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/98-request-profiling) episode is old but it is a sample of what Rails has already built in for such questions.